# How can I use maven's aggregation and inheritance to collect jars from child modules into parent's tarball

Tags: java, maven

I have a multimodule maven project with following structure:

```
root module
            module A
            module B
            module C
                     module C-1
                     module C-2
```

Module C is new in this project. Its goal is to define shared dependencies for sub-modules C-1 and C-2 (that is to be **parent** to them) and to **aggregate** jars that modules C-1 and C-2 build into single tar ball in module's C `target` directory.

This goal is achieved by:

- root `pom.xml` lists modules A, B, and C
- module C `pom.xml`lists modules C-1 and C-2 and declares shared dependencies; it also declares packaging as "pom"
- `maven-assembly-plugin` is used in modules C to find all `*.jar` files in it's children's `target` directory and pack them in tgz.

There are couple of problems I face with this implementation. Simple one was self-dependency of C-1 and C-2 - they inherit dependency to itself from C and hence refuse to compile. I addressed that wrapping dependencies into `dependencyManagement` in C. So looks like it's working.

I also do still have problem with Assembly plugin. When using wildchars in fileset values it preserves the directory structure in resulting tar ball and looks like you can't do anything about it. So having following in `bin.xml` of module C

```
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.jar</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*-javadoc.jar</exclude>
        </excludes>

    </fileSet>
```

results in **tarball** having structure

```
moduleC-version/moduleC-1/target/moduleC-1-version.jar
moduleC-version/moduleC-2/target/moduleC-2-version.jar
```

when I need just

```
moduleC-version/moduleC-1-version.jar
moduleC-version/moduleC-2-version.jar
```

Okey, that's not too important. The main problem is Reactor Build Order. Whatever I do it results in

1. module A
2. module B
3. module C
4. module C-1
5. module C-2

And that's a failure since build on module C complains

> Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bin: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]

My understanding is that the problem is in the sequence of Reactor Build Order - C-1 and C-2 should be built before C, - but I can't get how to manage it having C a parent to them and keeping on top of the module structure.

Comment: Most important part is to have a separate module (dist) which contains the configuration for maven-assembly-plugin. There you need to define all modules you like to package as dependencies to make sure each dependency is built before the module dist. Furthermore use a descriptor like [this](https://github.com/khmarbaise/assembly-examples/blob/master/assemblies-with-reactor/dist/proj1-assembly.xml) and structure like [this](https://github.com/khmarbaise/assembly-examples/tree/master/assemblies-with-reactor).

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, that's an option, why wouldn't you put it as an answer here? Though it looks like dist/pom.xml in this example doesn't need to list explicitly all the dependencies - Reactor will respect the order you list the modules, so all you need is to put dist last and get rid of dependencies.

Comment: I strongly recommend to define the modules you like to package  explicit as dependencies in `dist/pom.xml` otherwise your build will fail if you change for whatever reason (merging/changes/adding new modules) the order of the modules...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a distribution like package (zip for example) you have to define a separate module which contains the configuration for it.
Furthermore you need to define each module you would like to be packaged into as a dependency to make sure the build order is done correctly by maven.

The maven-assembly-plugin descriptor you have to use looks like [this:](https://github.com/khmarbaise/assembly-examples/blob/master/assemblies-with-reactor/dist/proj1-assembly.xml)

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>dist-assembly</id>

  <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
          <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
          <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
          <unpack>false</unpack>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

The structure of the projects looks more or like [this:](https://github.com/khmarbaise/assembly-examples/tree/master/assemblies-with-reactor)

```
+- pom.xml
+-- mod1
+-- mod2
+-- dist
```

Update:

If you need only the modules you can this as assembly descriptor instead:

```xml
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>modules</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

Comment: You were right about listing dependencies too - Reactor does order everything just fine based on modules sequence only **unless** I run it in multithreaded mode. Then the distribution project might indeed happen before it's dependencies. Still sad though that I have to maintain two lists of sub-projects - one as dependencies in distribution pom, and another as list of modules in aggregation pom. Would love to keep only one if possible.

Comment: The modules sequence should never be used cause it's not reliable. Define correct dependencies between the modules. Than it will work always...Also in case you are using multithread run...(mvn -T ...)